# How to Find Each Element in Nature

Tags: everyday-chemistry, reference-request, elements

I tried to google this but 'element' as a programming term complicated the search.

I'm looking for a site or article that covers how one would find each element in nature, in its most abundant form. For example, what's the best natural source/form of Sulfur? Beryllium? Tugsten? etc.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_chemical_element_discoveries

Answer (score 4):

The Wikipedia page for each element is probably the easiest place to start with. If you want some significantly more in-depth data, the USGS publishes [free-access mineral commodity summaries](http://minerals.usgs.gov/minerals/pubs/mcs/index.html) on many (but not all) elements, including information about their origin, abundance and applications. Other good sources are books, especially descriptive inorganic chemistry books, such as a few of [John Emsley's publications](http://johnemsley.com/book_home.html) including Nature's Building Blocks and The Elements, as well as many other college-level inorganic chemistry texts.

Answer (score 2):

The book *Chemistry of the Elements* by N. N. Greenwood is an absolutely huge handy tome full of information, which is organised by element or clusters of similar elements.

You'll find this as a handy overall chemistry reference, but most common ores of the elements (where applicable) and geological extraction information are also given. An essential to have on any chemistry shelf.

Comment: .. or any good inorganic chemistry text book (but this is indeed a good book).

Comment: From experience, not all inorganic books include the information like this one does. This book is essentially an inorganic textbook and data book at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [this site](http://www.webelements.com/). You will need to click on each element to get the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

http://elements.vanderkrogt.net/index.php is in my opinion the best site about how have been finden and discovered the elements.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

http://www.geokem.com/global-element-dist1.html#ge is more specific for your needs,more concise, less history more about actual source of the element.
[image]